# How can I get my remote dockerised website to be accessible

Tags: docker

I am trying to display my website from within a Docker container on a remote server but can't access it through my browser.

"This site can't be reached. {thisIp} refused to connect".

When looking on the server I can see the process is active website logging (every x seconds it tells me it's alive for the purpose of testing).

The server has port `5001` exposed and if I run the site using dotnet run I can access it and everything is fine.

I have come stuck with how to marry up the containerised website and the exposed port on the server, in my docker file I have `EXPOSE 80`.

When launching it tells me it is listening on http://::80

How can I get my containerised website to display through port 5001?

Comment: How are you trying to access the website? With `localhost` , or by using the dns of the server?

Comment: Using the IP of the server so I can access it on my machine when it's hosted on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to EXPOSE the port. You also have to map it to a specific port on your server.

If you're using simple `docker` shell command then you have to

```
docker run --publish 5001:80 your_docker_image
```

read more [in docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/run-containers/#overview).

If you're using `docker-compose` - then the syntax is a bit different:

```
# ... snip ...

ports:
  - 5001:80

# ... snip ...
```

read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you will have a look at the links now.

Comment: No problem. If you still have issues - please post some more details around how you are creating the containers.